# Mongo Shell on WebStorm not working

Tags: mongodb, webstorm

I am trying to open Mongo Shell from WebStorm. I have installed the Mongo plugin and also set up a mongodb server from the Mongo Explorer. After connecting when I am trying to open the Mongo shell I am getting this error:

```
Invalid command: localhost:27017/local
Options:

General options:
  -h [ --help ]                         show this usage information
  --version                             show version information
  -f [ --config ] arg                   configuration file specifying 
                                        additional options
  -v [ --verbose ] [=arg(=v)]           be more verbose (include multiple times
                                        for more verbosity e.g. -vvvvv)
  --quiet                               quieter output
  --port arg                            specify port number - 27017 by default
  --bind_ip arg                         comma separated list of ip addresses to
                                        listen on - all local ips by default
  --ipv6                                enable IPv6 support (disabled by 
                                        default)
  --maxConns arg                        max number of simultaneous connections 
                                        - 1000000 by default
  --logpath arg                         log file to send write to instead of 
                                        stdout - has to be a file, not 
                                        directory
  --logappend                           append to logpath instead of 
                                        over-writing
  --logRotate arg                       set the log rotation behavior 
                                        (rename|reopen)
  --timeStampFormat arg                 Desired format for timestamps in log 
                                        messages. One of ctime, iso8601-utc or 
                                        iso8601-local
  --pidfilepath arg                     full path to pidfile (if not set, no 
                                        pidfile is created)
  --keyFile arg                         private key for cluster authentication
  --noauth                              run without security
  --setParameter arg                    Set a configurable parameter
  --httpinterface                       enable http interface
  --transitionToAuth                    For rolling access control upgrade. 
                                        Attempt to authenticate over outgoing 
                                        connections and proceed regardless of 
                                        success. Accept incoming connections 
                                        with or without authentication.
  --clusterAuthMode arg                 Authentication mode used for cluster 
                                        authentication. Alternatives are 
                                        (keyFile|sendKeyFile|sendX509|x509)
  --networkMessageCompressors arg       Comma-separated list of compressors to 
                                        use for network messages
  --auth                                run with security
  --jsonp                               allow JSONP access via http (has 
                                        security implications)
  --rest                                turn on simple rest api
  --slowms arg (=100)                   value of slow for profile and console 
                                        log
  --profile arg                         0=off 1=slow, 2=all
  --cpu                                 periodically show cpu and iowait 
                                        utilization
  --sysinfo                             print some diagnostic system 
                                        information
  --noIndexBuildRetry                   don't retry any index builds that were 
                                        interrupted by shutdown
  --noscripting                         disable scripting engine
  --notablescan                         do not allow table scans

Windows Service Control Manager options:
  --install                             install Windows service
  --remove                              remove Windows service
  --reinstall                           reinstall Windows service (equivalent 
                                        to --remove followed by --install)
  --serviceName arg                     Windows service name
  --serviceDisplayName arg              Windows service display name
  --serviceDescription arg              Windows service description
  --serviceUser arg                     account for service execution
  --servicePassword arg                 password used to authenticate 
                                        serviceUser

Replication options:
  --oplogSize arg                       size to use (in MB) for replication op 
                                        log. default is 5% of disk space (i.e. 
                                        large is good)

Master/slave options (old; use replica sets instead):
  --master                              master mode
  --slave                               slave mode
  --source arg                          when slave: specify master as 
                                        <server:port>
  --only arg                            when slave: specify a single database 
                                        to replicate
  --slavedelay arg                      specify delay (in seconds) to be used 
                                        when applying master ops to slave
  --autoresync                          automatically resync if slave data is 
                                        stale

Replica set options:
  --replSet arg                         arg is <setname>[/<optionalseedhostlist
                                        >]
  --replIndexPrefetch arg               specify index prefetching behavior (if 
                                        secondary) [none|_id_only|all]
  --enableMajorityReadConcern           enables majority readConcern

Sharding options:
  --configsvr                           declare this is a config db of a 
                                        cluster; default port 27019; default 
                                        dir /data/configdb
  --shardsvr                            declare this is a shard db of a 
                                        cluster; default port 27018

SSL options:
  --sslOnNormalPorts                    use ssl on configured ports
  --sslMode arg                         set the SSL operation mode 
                                        (disabled|allowSSL|preferSSL|requireSSL
                                        )
  --sslPEMKeyFile arg                   PEM file for ssl
  --sslPEMKeyPassword arg               PEM file password
  --sslClusterFile arg                  Key file for internal SSL 
                                        authentication
  --sslClusterPassword arg              Internal authentication key file 
                                        password
  --sslCAFile arg                       Certificate Authority file for SSL
  --sslCRLFile arg                      Certificate Revocation List file for 
                                        SSL
  --sslDisabledProtocols arg            Comma separated list of TLS protocols 
                                        to disable [TLS1_0,TLS1_1,TLS1_2]
  --sslWeakCertificateValidation        allow client to connect without 
                                        presenting a certificate
  --sslAllowConnectionsWithoutCertificates 
                                        allow client to connect without 
                                        presenting a certificate
  --sslAllowInvalidHostnames            Allow server certificates to provide 
                                        non-matching hostnames
  --sslAllowInvalidCertificates         allow connections to servers with 
                                        invalid certificates
  --sslFIPSMode                         activate FIPS 140-2 mode at startup

Storage options:
  --storageEngine arg                   what storage engine to use - defaults 
                                        to wiredTiger if no data files present
  --dbpath arg                          directory for datafiles - defaults to 
                                        \data\db\ which is C:\data\db\ based on
                                        the current working drive
  --directoryperdb                      each database will be stored in a 
                                        separate directory
  --noprealloc                          disable data file preallocation - will 
                                        often hurt performance
  --nssize arg (=16)                    .ns file size (in MB) for new databases
  --quota                               limits each database to a certain 
                                        number of files (8 default)
  --quotaFiles arg                      number of files allowed per db, implies
                                        --quota
  --smallfiles                          use a smaller default file size
  --syncdelay arg (=60)                 seconds between disk syncs (0=never, 
                                        but not recommended)
  --upgrade                             upgrade db if needed
  --repair                              run repair on all dbs
  --repairpath arg                      root directory for repair files - 
                                        defaults to dbpath
  --journal                             enable journaling
  --nojournal                           disable journaling (journaling is on by
                                        default for 64 bit)
  --journalOptions arg                  journal diagnostic options
  --journalCommitInterval arg           how often to group/batch commit (ms)

WiredTiger options:
  --wiredTigerCacheSizeGB arg           maximum amount of memory to allocate 
                                        for cache; defaults to 1/2 of physical 
                                        RAM
  --wiredTigerStatisticsLogDelaySecs arg (=0)
                                        seconds to wait between each write to a
                                        statistics file in the dbpath; 0 means 
                                        do not log statistics
  --wiredTigerJournalCompressor arg (=snappy)
                                        use a compressor for log records 
                                        [none|snappy|zlib]
  --wiredTigerDirectoryForIndexes       Put indexes and data in different 
                                        directories
  --wiredTigerCollectionBlockCompressor arg (=snappy)
                                        block compression algorithm for 
                                        collection data [none|snappy|zlib]
  --wiredTigerIndexPrefixCompression arg (=1)
                                        use prefix compression on row-store 
                                        leaf pages
Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Can you tell me which command are you using for establishing connection?

Comment: Not using any command. After creating the mongo server I am connecting using the 'Connect to server' option in the mongo explorer

Comment: Use mongo instead of mongod in path to executable.

Comment: It worked. Thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To add **mongodb** functionality in webstorm, do the following steps.

1. Go to **File -> Settings -> Plugins**

[image: Setting Page of webstorm]

2. Click on **Browse Repositories**

[image: Browse Repositories]

3. Search for **mongo plugin** and click on install button. It will start downloading mongo plugin

[image]
[image]

4. Click on Restart button and then click ok. It will restart the webstorm.

[image]

[image]

5. Now Go to **File --> Setting --> Other Settings --> Mongo Servers.** In **Path to Mongo Shell** give path of the mongo executable. You can check the path of the mongo executable by typing **which mongo** in the terminal

   - For ubuntu generally its **/usr/bin/mongo**
   - For Mac generally its **/usr/local/bin/mongo**
6. Then click on **test** to check if correct binaries are loaded or not

[image]

7. Now click on the plus button to add a server. It is default configuration. So just click ok.

[image]

8. Now go to **View --> Tools Windows --> Mongo Explorer** . You will be able to see your database.

[image]

Comment: This works for reading from the database, however when viewing a document, the 'edit' button in the plugin is disabled with zero clues about what conditions would enable it. Very frustrating.

Comment: @DaveMunger you have to check whether proper write permission have given to database

Comment: @PrashantPokhriyal I don't think that's the issue. What I have found in further use is that for some reason, the edit button is enabled only when certain keys ("fields") are clicked. This is within the same document. When I click edit in that case, the entire document is editable. It certainly seems like a bug to me.

Comment: @DaveMunger I had the same problem and was able to edit by first selecting the object ID ("_id") and choosing "Edit". This opened an edit panel in the lower half of the screen that enabled me to edit all fields for the record. Does this work for you?

Comment: @DaveMunger good point. I have same issue and that's uncomfortable. and if I click by mistake a remove button right next of edit, the document is gone without any alert or message. I pretty sure data is important when we treated.